# How to connect to Gemfire docker instance?

Tags: gemfire, geode

How to connect to docker gemfire instance through docker run command?

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND   CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                NAMES
8faffdfdbfb9   apachegeode/geode   "gfsh"    3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   1099/tcp, 7070/tcp, 8080/tcp, 10334/tcp, 40404/tcp   compassionate_chebyshev
```

I tried using gfsh but no luck.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a bit more detail: What command did you run to launch your original container? When you say that you 'tried gfsh', how did you run that? What image are you using?

Comment: If you're able, I'd suggest using the `gemfire` image described here: https://hub.docker.com/r/gemfire/gemfire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me using `apachegeode/geode:latest`

To run container:

```
➜  ~ docker run -it  apachegeode/geode
```

Once the container is running, you can open a shell and run gfsh:

```
➜  ~ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND   CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                NAMES
8bd2058ed614   apachegeode/geode   "gfsh"    3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   1099/tcp, 7070/tcp, 8080/tcp, 10334/tcp, 40404/tcp   friendly_brattain
➜  ~ docker exec -it 8bd2058ed614 /bin/bash
bash-5.1# gfsh
    _________________________     __
   / _____/ ______/ ______/ /____/ /
  / /  __/ /___  /_____  / _____  /
 / /__/ / ____/  _____/ / /    / /
/______/_/      /______/_/    /_/    1.15.1

Monitor and Manage Apache Geode
gfsh>
```

Comment: Once you exit from gfsh shell then how to login in back again?

Comment: I have changed the instructions after your comment. I have realised that if you run first gfsh, the container is shut down when you exit. So better open a shell on the container, and run gfsh from there